# require is working jsx file but url() resolve is not wroking in sass file - webpack

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-style-loader

I am facing this strange issue with **Webpack**. After spending hours couldn't find solution.

In my jsx file when I a try to set image source via this

```
let img = require('../../../img/imgN.png');
```

It is working perfectly but when I try to set the background image using scss via

```
$bg-img: url('../img/bg-img.png');
```

Image is not getting loading by webpack.

This is my webpack file

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    main: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './src/index.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
   loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'react-hot!babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
        loaders: ["style", "css?sourceMap", "sass?sourceMap"]
      },
      {
          test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
          include: path.join(__dirname, 'img'),
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=30000'
     } // inline base64 URLs for <=30k images, direct URLs for the rest
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was occurring because of using **sourceMap** with **style-loader**.

There is some issue on [github](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader/pull/96) for the same problem.

**Solution:**

1 . **While source-maps is enabled**

Style-loader uses a Blob, so it requires absolute urls to work.

Changed `publicPath: '/public/',` to

```
publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/public/',
```

It worked.

2. **Without source-maps** 
   Just remove source map from style loaders.

Now style-loader will use an inline style tag, so there is no problem.

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'sass'),
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to see if $bg-img: url('~/img/bg-img.png'); would work? When I was trying out webpack in my bootstrap.scss files I had to modify the font url's using ~ (I think I read it somewhere but ya just giving you something to try)

Comment: Still not working but
Now I see this  `background: url("/img/bg-img.png") center center;` There is no hash code associated with it(which is done by file-loader or url-loader in webpack). Previously I was having `background: url("/img/sf9ds7f987dsf9dsf987.png") center center;`.